# Error pasando objeto por sesion en php

Tags: php, session, poo

Estoy realizando un login, y el tipo de usuario es un objeto diferente, ese objeto en el codigo que consulta si funciona bien, utilice un var_dump a la variable de session donde lo usé y funciona bien, epro cuando lo envio ya no funciona.

## **Login.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once '../Modelo/PDOConex.php';

if((!$nameUser = trim($_POST['user'])) || (!$password = md5(trim($_POST['pass']) ) ) ){
header('location:../');
}

try{
$stmt = $db_con->prepare("SELECT 
    idUsuarios,
    Cuenta,
    Contra
FROM 
    Usuarios 
WHERE 
    Cuenta=:usuario");

$stmt->execute(array(":usuario"=>$nameUser));
$fila = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if($fila['Contra']==$password){ //Credenciales correctas

    require_once 'Log/getTipo.php';

    switch (getTipo($fila['idUsuarios'], $db_con)){

        case 'Administrativo':
            require_once 'Log/LoginAdmin.php';
            $_SESION['Usuario'] = serialize(logAdmin($fila['idUsuarios'], $db_con));
            $_SESION['Tipo']= 'Administrativo';
            break;
        case 'Docente':
            require_once 'Log/LoginDocente.php';
            $_SESION['Usuario'] = logDocente($fila['idUsuarios']);
            $_SESION['Tipo']= 'Docente';
            break;
        case 'Estudiante':
            require_once 'Log/LoginEstud.php';
            $_SESION['Usuario'] = logEst($fila['idUsuarios']);
            $_SESION['Tipo']= 'Estudiante';
            break;
        case 'Acudiente':
            require_once 'Log/LoginAcud.php';
            $_SESION['Usuario'] = logAcud($fila['idUsuarios']);
            $_SESION['Tipo']= 'Acudiente';
            break;
        default:
            echo "0";
            break;
    }
}else{
    echo '0'; // Credenciales incorrectas
}
}catch(PDOException $e){
echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

## **index.php**

```
<?php
require_once 'Controlador/Usuarios/Acudientes.php';
require_once 'Controlador/Usuarios/Administrativos.php';
require_once 'Controlador/Usuarios/Docentes.php';
require_once 'Controlador/Usuarios/Estudiantes.php';
session_start();
```

// **Error** No recibe el objeto, aqui var_dump imprime false...

```
$_SESSION['Usuario'] = unserialize($_SESSION['Usuario'])
if(isset($_SESSION['Usuario'])){
    header('location:Pages/login.php');
}else{

switch($_SESSION['Tipo']){
    case 'Administrativo':
        if(count($_SESSION['Usuario']->getId_Colegio())>1){
            header('location:preAdmin.php');
        }else{
            header('location:indexAdmin.php');
        }
        break;
    case 'Docente':
        if(count($_SESSION['Usuario']->getId_Colegio())>1){
            header('location:preDocente.php');
        }else{
            header('location:indexDocente.php');
        }
        break;
    case 'Estudiante':
        header('location:indexEstudiante.php');
        break;
    case 'Acudiente':
        header('location:indexAcudiante.php');
        break;
    default:
        header('location:Controlador/logout.php');
        break;
    }
}
```

¿En que estoy fallando?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tras ejecutar la línea que pone `$_SESSION['Usuario'] = unserialize($_SESSION['Usuario']);` se guardará el valor tratado como el contenido de la variable de sesión `$_SESSION['Usuario']` sobreescribiendo el valor original, por lo que la siguiente vez que pases por esa misma línea [`unserialize`](http://php.net/unserialize) devolverá `false` porque no será capaz de funcionar por segunda vez con unos datos ya tratados, generando también una notificación de tipo `E_NOTICE` (que puedes estar filtrando dependiendo de la configuración de tu PHP).

Deberías usar una variable temporal diferente a la de sesión (para no modificar y corromper su contenido) para trabajar con los datos devueltos por [`unserialize`](http://php.net/unserialize):

```
$datos = unserialize($_SESSION['Usuario']);
switch($_SESSION['Tipo']){
    case 'Administrativo':
        if(count($datos->getId_Colegio())>1){
            header('location:preAdmin.php');
        }else{
            header('location:indexAdmin.php');
        }
        break;
    case 'Docente':
        if(count($datos->getId_Colegio())>1){
            header('location:preDocente.php');
        }else{
            header('location:indexDocente.php');
        }
        break;
    case 'Estudiante':
        header('location:indexEstudiante.php');
        break;
    case 'Acudiente':
        header('location:indexAcudiante.php');
        break;
    default:
        header('location:Controlador/logout.php');
        break;
    }
}
```

Además, no siempre usas [`serialize`](http://php.net/serialize) para guardar los datos en dicha variable de sesión, por lo que deberías hacer homogéneo tu código antes de seguir o usar una variable de sesión diferente que siempre contenga el mismo tipo de contenido.

Ejemplo mínimo funcional:

```
/* Iniciamos el entorno de sesiones */
session_start();

/* Definimos una clase mínima con la que trabajar */
class Usuario
{
    /* El valor inicial del número al instanciar la clase será 0 */
    private $numero = 0;

    public function getNumero()
    {
        return $this->numero;
    }

    public function setNumero($numero)
    {
        $this->numero = $numero;
    }
}

/* Si no estaba definido el índice en la variable súperglobal
  de sesión instanciamos un nuevo usuario */ 
if (!isset($_SESSION['Usuario'])) {
    $_SESSION['Usuario'] = new Usuario();
}
/* Si en algún momento el contenido no es una instancia de Usuario lo decimos */
if (! $_SESSION['Usuario'] instanceof Usuario) {
    die('$_SESSION[\'Usuario\'] no es una instancia de Usuario.');
}
/* Mostramos el valor actual */
echo $_SESSION['Usuario']->getNumero() ."\n";
/* Incrementamos en uno el valor */
$_SESSION['Usuario']->setNumero($_SESSION['Usuario']->getNumero() + 1);
```

Como puedes ver, cada vez que cargamos la página se incrementa en uno la propiedad `$numero` de la clase `Usuario`. Eso es porque se guarda el estado de la clase en la variable de sesión.

Comment: No he usado el serialize en todas las partes por que solo he probado alli, y lo use sin serializarlo y no funcionó, use una variable temporal y tampoco funcionó.

Comment: El problema es que tu código no es homogéneo ni incoherente y no representa un [MCVE](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Voy a editar mi respuesta para ponerte un ejemplo funcional.

Comment: Bueno, mira, encontre el error y era muy bobo, en un archivo usaba $_SESION en vez de $_SESSION, sin embargo por lo correcto de tu intervencion la colocaré como mejor respuesta, muchas gracias.

Comment: ¡Puf! Fíjate que lo vi y pensé que fue errata al copiar aquí (como dijiste que te funcionaba una vez y la segunda vez no supuse que estaba bien). Gracias por el detalle ;)